# Make an Exchange 2007 address book container that shows all items in AD container

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2007

I have generated a bunch of distribution lists in an AD container and now I want to show those in a container in the Exchange 2007 address book.

This does not work:

```
New-AddressList 
-Name "ORG ABC Distribution Lists" 
-RecipientFilter { (DistinguishedName -like "*OU=DistributionLists,OU=abc,DC=org,DC=com") }

New-AddressList : Invalid filter: 'The wild card * is not supported for this attribute type.'
```

I noticed when I create the lists (using PowerShell), they automatically get 3 values for the `ShowInAddressBook` property.

Modifying the `ShowInAddressBook` manually is easy and does the job. However, I don't manage to automate this, it is difficult to update this multivalue property. It is the idea to set up a synchronization, so automation is key.

This works but I have to clear all values for `ShowInAddressBook`:

```
$ldap=[ADSI]"LDAP://OU=DistributionLists,OU=ORG-ABC-GROUP,DC=ORG,DC=com"
$srch = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($ldap)

$srch.findAll() | % {
       $objList = [ADSI]$("LDAP://{0}" -f $_.Properties.get_Item('distinguishedName').Item(0))

       #clear all ShowInAddressBook values
       $objList.PutEX(1,'showInAddressBook', $null) 
       $objList.SetInfo()

       #set one showInAddressBook value       
       $objList.put('showInAddressBook',"CN=ORG ABC Distribution Lists,CN=All Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=ORG,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=ORG,DC=com")
       $objList.SetInfo()
}
```

Comment: You should be using `RecipientContainer` instead I would think for this

Comment: New-AddressList does not have a -RecipientContainer option, unfortunately

Comment: First idea I have then is: Do you have any custom attributes free that you could use for those groups then? Then you could use a filter with `CustomAttribute1` for example

Comment: Good idea, might give it a try ...

Comment: It works. I may not forget to Update-AddressList after every sync.

Comment: Still I would like to remove 1 of the ShowInAddressBook values and leave the others in place, don't know how to do that.

Comment: I now excluded my lists from the RecipientFilter of the AddressList that I do not want my lists in - based on CustomAttribute1.